# How to configure ejabberd with Oauth support

Tags: oauth, token, ejabberd

I've tried to follow the steps [here](http://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/guide/oauth/) to configure ejabberd OAuth but failed. ejabberd.yml looks like below :

```
-
port: 5280
module: ejabberd_http
request_handlers:
  "/websocket": ejabberd_http_ws
  "/log": mod_log_http
  # OAuth support:
  "/oauth": ejabberd_oauth
  # ReST API:
  "/api": mod_http_api
##  "/pub/archive": mod_http_fileserver
web_admin: true
http_bind: true
## register: true
captcha: true
```

**Note** : I've restart the ejabberd.

URL that I used (this is the page where I entered **User**, **Server** and **Password**) : `http://mytestsite.com:5280/oauth/authorization_token?response_type=token&client_id=Client1&redirect_uri=http://mytestsite.com&scope=user_get_roster+sasl_auth`

I've been redirected to `https://mytestsite.com/?error=access_denied&state=&gws_rd=ssl`

According to the tutorial, once I enabled /oauth and /api in the .yml file, the following URL should redirect me to `http://mytestsite.com/?access_token=RHIT8DoudzOctdzBhYL9bYvXz28xQ4Oj&token_type=bearer&expires_in=3600&scope=user_get_roster+sasl_auth&state=`

Comment: How do you authenticate user ? Is your backend properly configured ? Are JID + login correct in the form ? Can you authenticate properly with same credential over XMPP ? Can you authenticate properly in admin web interface ?

Comment: How do you authenticate user ?
  -- internal authentication.

Is your backend properly configured ? 
  -- Yes, my backend has been configured properly.
  
Are JID + login correct in the form ? 
 -- Yes, correct.
 
Can you authenticate properly with same credential over XMPP ? 
 -- Yes, tested using XMPP clients (Adium & Swift) and it's working.

Can you authenticate properly in admin web interface
 -- Yes, can.

Comment: How did you configure `oauth_access` parameter ?

Comment: Hi Mickaël, did you refer to oauth_access in ejabberd_oauth.erl ? I used the default configuration without changing anything in ejabberd_oauth.erl / .beam. Or the oauth_access should be added in ejabberd.yml ?

Comment: Yes, you need oauth_access otherwise no one can create a token. We will update the documentation to make that clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must defined `oauth_access` parameter in ejabberd.yml config file, otherwise, no one can create an oauth token.

We will update the documentation to make it more accurate on that part.

Comment: is that something like this ? :- commands_admin_access: configure
commands:
  - add_commands: user
oauth_expire: 3600
oauth_access: all

Comment: I've tried what your suggestion (enabled the "oauth_access: all") but it's not working. Is there anything else did I miss? Appreciate if you can give any hints on how can I debug this

Comment: Hello Mickaël Rémond, it's working now! I re-installed my ejabberd and enabled oauth_access in ejabberd.yml. thanks mate!

Comment: Hi Mickaël, on my side generating an OAuth Access Token works, but I always encounter 401 Unauthorized errors when I request the Web Services. I published an other Stackoverflow post for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35287578/ejabberd-oauth-rest-401-unauthorized, can you help me on this ?

Comment: Hi @Shakhassan, I have the same issue and unable to get this work. If you could post the full .yml file will be really helpful. I think I am making some mistake in placing this piece of code commands_admin_access: configure commands: - add_commands: user oauth_expire: 3600 oauth_access: all.  

Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: @JP Apologies for the long delay response here is snapshot of my ejabberd.yml :

-
  port: 5280
  module: ejabberd_http
  request_handlers:
    "/websocket": ejabberd_http_ws
    "/log": mod_log_http
    "/oauth": ejabberd_oauth
    "/api": mod_http_api
  web_admin: true
  http_bind: true
  captcha: false

commands_admin_access: configure
commands:
  - add_commands: user
oauth_expire: 3600
oauth_access: all

Comment: @shkhssn, Thanks for the notes and it worked, sorry for the delayed response.