# Ejabberd OAuth / REST 401 Unauthorized

Tags: api, rest, oauth, ejabberd

I'm trying to request the Ejabberd REST Web Services with the `/api/connected_users` endpoint but the request always returns me 401 Unauthorized HTTP errors.

Here is my OAuth configuration.

```
 - 
port: 5280
module: ejabberd_http
request_handlers:
  "/websocket": ejabberd_http_ws
  # OAuth Support
  "/oauth": ejabberd_oauth
  # ReST API:
  "/api": mod_http_api
web_admin: true
http_bind: true
register: true
captcha: false

...    

commands_admin_access: configure
commands:
  - add_commands: user
oauth_expire: 3600
oauth_access: all
```

As explained in the documentation I use the following URL to generate an OAuth 2 Access Token for the `admin` user.

`http://localhost:5280/oauth/authorization_token?response_type=token&client_id=myclient&redirect_uri=http://localhost:5280&scope=sasl_auth`

It returns me my OAuth Token.

`http://localhost:5280/?access_token=oLn8Hebh051l2PdCM15tSvHrEI25CpBs&token_type=bearer&expires_in=3600&scope=sasl_auth&state=`

Finally to request the `api/connected_users` endpoint I do the following.

`curl -v -X GET -H "X-Admin: true" -H "Authorization: Bearer oLn8Hebh051l2PdCM15tSvHrEI25CpBs" http://localhost:5280/api/connected_users`

But it always returns me 401 Unauthorized errors.

In my `ejabberd.log` file I have this.

```
2016-02-09 09:47:12.177 [info] <0.497.0>@ejabberd_listener:accept:333 (#Port<0.16419>) Accepted connection 127.0.0.1:62395 -> 127.0.0.1:5280
2016-02-09 09:47:12.177 [debug] <0.546.0>@ejabberd_http:init:154 S: [{[<<"websocket">>],ejabberd_http_ws},{[<<"oauth">>],ejabberd_oauth},{[<<"api">>],mod_http_api},{[<<"register">>],mod_register_web},{[<<"admin">>],ejabberd_web_admin},{[<<"http-bind">>],mod_http_bind}]
2016-02-09 09:47:12.177 [info] <0.546.0>@ejabberd_http:init:158 started: {gen_tcp,#Port<0.16419>}
2016-02-09 09:47:12.177 [debug] <0.546.0>@ejabberd_http:process_header:281 (#Port<0.16419>) http query: 'GET' <<"/api/connected_users">>
2016-02-09 09:47:12.177 [debug] <0.546.0>@ejabberd_http:process:353 [<<"api">>,<<"connected_users">>] matches [<<"api">>]
2016-02-09 09:47:12.178 [info] <0.546.0>@mod_http_api:log:388 Admin call connected_users [] from 127.0.0.1:62395
```

So how to configure Ejabberd to allow the `admin` user to request all the Ejabberd REST Web Services ?

My users are stored in Mysql, as OAuth Tokens are stored in Mnesia could it be the problem ?

Thanks,

Baptiste

Comment: make sure you have enabled the modules supporting the OAuth commands in ejabberd.yml in module section . provide detail log and module configuration.

Comment: Hi Sunil and thanks for your response, what you indicate is written in the docs "the modules supporting the OAuth commands you want to use", but this is the only instruction for modules and OAuth / REST I found. So what are those "modules supporting the OAuth commands" ? I do not understand what I have to do, in the configuration section of the docs http://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/guide/configuration their is nothing about an "OAuth" or "REST" module. Could you explain me which modules to add in the "modules" section then ? (I've added "mod_http_api" but still encounter authorization errors).

Comment: @BaptisteGaillard have you solved it somehow ? I am facing same

Comment: I have the same problem. Please help.

Comment: @BaptisteGaillard Were you able to resolve this issue? If so, please tell.

Comment: Hi, because I posted this message in 2016 I do not remember exactly what I did. I only worked with Ejjaberd to implement a Proof Of Concept and I believe I did not solve the problem at that time. Sorry to not being able to help you on this.

Answer (score 1):

Be sure you are using the @host when entering username if it's specified in that way in ejabberd.yml. I wasn't receiving any response from REST requests because I was using just admin for user, when should be admin@somehost in user name.

Please let me know if this doesn't help.

Answer (score 1):

make sure you enter correct User(jid): ( User (jid): user@hostname)

it worked for me.